# coffeescript and sugarjs ~ issue with number (50).pad(5)

Tags: coffeescript, sugar.js

I am using sugarjs. When using the numbers api it doesn't go well with coffeescript. I am thinking it is the brackets..what is a better way to do this.

(50).pad(5) gets transalated to 50..pad(5)

how to keep the brackets intact.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to keep the brackets intact ? They're not needed. It works fine this way